# Using a 2-dimensional array, segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I look in different web sites.. but anything that make me understand whats the problem.. I just started programming in C. The task was drawing a chessboard using a 2 dimension array and build a function that alternates black and white(using appropriate symbols).

```
#include <stdio.h>

char makeChessBoard(int length,int width, char board[width][length]) {
  int i;
  int j;
  for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
   // printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if((i+j)%2 == 0)
        board[i][j] = "[#]";
      else
        board[i][j] = "[ ]"; 
    }//for
  }//for
  //return 0;

}//makeChessBoard


int main()
{
int x = 9;
int y = 9;
char initialBoard[x][y];
char chessBoard[x][y];
makeChessBoard(initialBoard[x][y],x,y);
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      printf("%s", chessBoard[i][j]);
    }//for
  }//for


}//main
```

Comment: Hmmm A 9x9 chessboard?

Comment: can you give an approximate location where it crashes?

Comment: `printf("%s", chessBoard[i][j]);` is not going to work as `chessBoard` is not initialized.

Comment: Suggest turn on all compiler warnings.  That will save you time.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. And the warnings and errors emitted from this code a numerous. [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/ziQvyh). Address every one of them, then debug your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your calling of function `makeChessBoard(initialBoard[x][y],x,y);` and function definition is different it should be:  `(int length,int width, char board[width][length])`.

2) In function makeChessBoard change `board[i][j] = "[#]";` to `board[i][j] = '#';`. Similarly change `board[i][j] = "[ ]";` to `board[i][j] = ' ';`.

3) While printing you should print the values of `initialBoard` as you have populated the values in this 2D array, so change `printf("%s", chessBoard[i][j]);` to `printf("[%c]", initialBoard[i][j]);`.

4) Array index start from zero, so if you are printing chess board `x` and `y` should be set to `8`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char makeChessBoard(int length,int width, char board[width][length]) 
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < width; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < length; j++) 
        {
            if( ((i+j) % 2) == 0)
                board[i][j] = '#';
            else
                board[i][j] = ' '; 
        }//for
    }//for
}//makeChessBoard

int main()
{
    int x = 8;
    int y = 8;
    int i,j;
    char initialBoard[x][y];
    //char chessBoard[x][y]; /* You are not using this 2-D array */
    makeChessBoard(x,y,initialBoard);
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++) 
        {
            printf("[%c]", initialBoard[i][j]);
        }//for
        printf("\n");
    }//for
}//main
```

**Output**:

```
[#][ ][#][ ][#][ ][#][ ]
[ ][#][ ][#][ ][#][ ][#]
[#][ ][#][ ][#][ ][#][ ]
[ ][#][ ][#][ ][#][ ][#]
[#][ ][#][ ][#][ ][#][ ]
[ ][#][ ][#][ ][#][ ][#]
[#][ ][#][ ][#][ ][#][ ]
[ ][#][ ][#][ ][#][ ][#]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn your warnings on

```
makeChessBoard(initialBoard[x][y],x,y);
```

should be

```
makeChessBoard(x, y, initialBoard);
```

---

```
board[i][j] = "[#]"; /* you can't assign a string, use a char e.g: '#' */
```

same for

```
board[i][j] = "[ ]";
```

---

Finally, you are printing characters, use:

```
printf("%c", chessBoard[i][j]);
```

instead of

```
printf("%s", chessBoard[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `makeChessboard` like this:

```
 makeChessBoard(initialBoard[x][y],x,y);
```

but it's defined like this:

```
 char makeChessBoard(int length,int width, char board[width][length])
```

Notice that you are passing the array at the wrong parameter position.

Furthermore you are passing a specific array element (at x,y), instead of the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the code with warnings enabled (gcc -Wall ...) and check what the compiler will tell you.
The immediate reason for segfault is probably char instead of char*.